# Outputting to a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and I'm looking to output to a pandas dataframe so that another package can pick it up.

Can somebody please explain what I need to do in practice?

For example, to output a table to a crosstab, I would do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

income_final = 
pd.read_csv("D:\\data\\income17-18_data.csv")

income2 = income_final[(income_final.benefits == 1)]    

pd.crosstab(income2.benefits, income2.taxes)
```

How would I go about outputting this into a pandas dataframe?

Much appreciated.

Comment: crosstab already returns a DataFrame object just assign it to a variable `df = pd.crosstab(income2.benefits, income2.taxes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on pandas [documentation of read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) the instruction:

```
pd.read_csv("D:\\data\\income17-18_data.csv")
```

returns a DataFrame, so you may store it on a variable to pass it as argument to other funcion or method:

```
dataFrame18 = pd.read_csv("D:\\data\\income17-18_data.csv")
```

So you can use dataFrame18. If you have doubts, check the type of a with:

```
type(dataFrame18)
```

After loading the data on a var.

Best regards,
ealcober.